# Final Project intro C++ programming class

Tags: c++

So I need help with this problem!!

You are rolling a red, a yellow and a green standard dice (whose sides each have the numbers 1-6 on them) and combine them to a 3-digit number by using the red value as the ones place, the yellow value as the tens place and the green value as the hundreds place. For example, if you rolled a 3 with red, a 5 with yellow and 2 with green then the combined 3-digit number would be 253.

You repeat this process and your job is to continuously find the average of all of those 3-digit numbers.

More precisely, you need to first read an integer that tells you how many 3-digit numbers you'll be averaging. Next, you need to read the red value, then the yellow value, then the green value of the first throw and print out the corresponding 3-digit number as well as the current average with one decimal place. Then you repeat this process for the given number of rounds.

This is what I have so far, I think that I'm pretty close just missing some stuff but I can't figure out what it is:

\\

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int i;
    int Red=0;
    int Yellow=0;
    int Green=0;
    double Average=0;
    int Rounds=0;
    int together=0;
    scanf("%d", &Rounds);
    for (i=0;i<Rounds;i++){
    scanf("%d %d %d", &Green, &Yellow, &Red);
    }
    for (i=0;i<Rounds;i++){
    together =((Green*100)+(Yellow*10)+Red);
    Average=together/Rounds;
    printf("you rolled: %d, current average: %.1lf\n", together, Average);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

\\

Comment: You should also explain what the problem is. (It's proibably integer division at `together/Rounds`, cast one of the values to double to avoid rounding).

Comment: When you're having trouble with a project like this, *try something simpler.* Try writing a program that reads 10 numbers and prints the average at each step. Once you have that working perfectly, this project will look much easier.

Comment: You are reading the values `Green`, `Yellow`, `Red` in a loop but you don't use them. In the next iteration you overwrite them. You only use the values from last iteration.

Comment: You could combine both loops to one larger loop where you read the values and add them to `together`.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding the problem correctly your code needs to keep a running total of the value to be averaged where as right now your code never adds the next value to the total to be divided.

Also, the average needs to be the sum of the numbers divided by the number of integers summed: (i + 1). The variable rounds should only be used for deciding how many times to loop.

Another thing that is probably causing a problem is the values for green, yellow, and red never change in the final for loop. 
You need to take the logic in the first for loop and have it be the first line of the final loop. Then simply remove the first for loop. 
Hope this helps:

```
     for (i=0;i<Rounds;i++){
      scanf("%d %d %d", &Green, &Yellow, &Red);
      together += ((Green*100)+(Yellow*10)+Red);
      Average=together/(i + 1);
      printf("you rolled: %d, current average: %.1lf\n", together, Average);
     }
```

Also as mentioned above Integer division is probably causing an issue too. Maybe use doubles instead of ints.

Comment: I'd also add that the problem statement says "you need to read the **red** value, *then* the **yellow** value, *then* the **green** value", which is not what the code does. To avoid the integer division you can just use `double Average = together / (i + 1.0);`.

Comment: @Bob__ Good point, OP could split up the scanf statement into 3 so it follows the instructions more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

i think you forgot to create a variable to hold the combined number:

```
num = ((green*100)+(yellow*10)+red);

// COMPLETE CODE

    #include <stdio.h>
 
    int main(void){
      int i;
      int red=0;
      int yellow=0;
      int green=0;
      double average=0;
      int rounds=0;
      int combined_number=0;
      int num;
      scanf("%d", &rounds);
      for (i=0;i<rounds;i++){
        scanf("%d %d %d", &red, &yellow, &green);
        num = ((green*100)+(yellow*10)+red);

        combined_number += ((green*100)+(yellow*10)+red);
        average=(double) combined_number/(i + 1);
        printf("%d. you rolled: %d, current average:%.1lf\n",i+1,num,average);
     }
    return 0;
  }
```